# Optimal constant seed for Mersenne Twister in C++ 11

Tags: c++, c++11, random, random-seed, mersenne-twister

My use case is: I need random numbers, but just for graphics (not for cryptography). I need to be able to get the same image (result) for 2 renderings/runs. For example, using `time()` as seed would not create the same result for the next run. So I need a *constant* seed.

The documentation for the Mersenne Twister says that it does not like 0 as seed, it also dislikes certain bit combinations. For such cases it is said to take up to 800000 calls until it delivers good random numbers again. For speed reasons I don't want to spend the overhead of 800000 calls.
Ideally I would need some nice and trusted value(s) that I can use as seed directly.

Comment: Have you tried `4`?

Comment: Do you really need truly random results when testing?

Comment: Why do you need the same result for two runs? If the answer is "reproduciblity" then you should get your seed from a standard source (like timestamp) and log it, and make it optionally overridable as a command line argument. This is the approach used by e.g. gtest.

Comment: Hi Nir,  i shoot particles based on "random" position. I need the same result because otherwise i will get animation flickering (particles would change position from image to next image).   Imagine a camera fly through.  I will also check using the 3d position as seed, as this looks more stable. Last, but not least, is optimal support when objects in the scene are animated as well. if an obstacle moves, and my particle is blocked all particles that are shot later would derail (flicker). Most likely i will pre compute sequences of random numbers to prevent that.

Answer (score 1):

Just pick whatever number you want.

The thing you have to bear in mind is that the standards that cryptography experts and algorithm analysts use for "high-quality randomness" are almost certainly well above the standards needed for your project, especially for a well-tested algorithm like Mersenne Twister. Most of those standards are designed for bug-testing scenarios or statistical analysis, where a "sub-par quality" sequence of random numbers might have the potential to miss important test cases or where numbers might be skewing the expected mean/median/standard deviation of the results.

It's extremely unlikely that those are concerns in your application.

Comment: I tried 0, 4 and 2384572893 as seeds.  Results look extremly similar. I did see some structure with 0 that would go away with 4 and 2384572893, but this could be pure chance.

Comment: Mersenne Twister has a problem when all elements in its state array are zero -- this is a different thing than the number or sequence you pass to `seed` or the constructor.  An algorithm is used to spread entropy from the seed value into the state array which avoids degenerate situations.  So this answer is right, just pick whatever number you want.